# Add service reference using OpenAPI and VS2022

Tags: c#, openapi, nswag

I have an OpenAPI-file with the following three endpoints:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/rest/v1/ConvoyManager/Version": { ... },
    "/rest/v1/Dispatcher/Version": { ... },
    "/rest/v1/JobManager/Version": { ... },
  "components": { }
}
```

Now I want to use that service in a client-project. To do so I added a service-reference in VS2022. This will create the source-code for that spec and I can see it in the obj-folder. When I look into it, there is only a single class with three methods, instead of three classes having one single method:

```
class GeneratedClass
{
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> VersionAsync()
    {
        return VersionAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> Version2Async()
    {
        return Version2Async(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
    public virtual System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> Version3Async()
    {
        return Version3Async(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
    }
    ...
}
```

Is there any way I can generate three classes or at least get the names of the endpoints included in the functions being generated? So in my client-code I can see which method refers to which endpoint. Of course I could just split my spec-file into three and add each as a seperate service, however I hope there's a way without modiyfing that file.